# How do I start MSDE2000A (mssql$netsdk) from cmd in Windows 7?

Tags: sql, database, msde, msde2000

I'm trying to install MSDE2000A on a Windows 7 machine, and the database book I'm using described doing so through the command line.  First I installed it to C:\< folder >.  Everything went fine (except for a Windows 7 compatibility issue notice), until I started to actually run it.  I was in the directory in the command line, and I typed net start mssql$netsdk.  As a result I get the response

"System error 5 has occurred.

Acess is denied."

After trying to look up a solution, I found that Windows 7 had an issue with developer stuff being put outside of users' directories, so then I installed it again, this time in C:\Users\< username >\< folder >.  The same problem occurred.

Where do I go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see the issue about developer stuff being installed outside user directories? I've never had any problems. Your issue here, as mrdenny says, is that you're trying to start and stop services from a non-administrator command prompt - installation path shouldn't matter.

Comment: I forgot the exact nature of the problem, but while searching for a solution to my problem, I saw where somebody had a different problem of the same basic category and was able to fix it that way, so that's why I made the attempt.  I hadn't programmed much on Windows 7, so I wasn't sure whether to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to start the service from a command line window start the window in administrative mode.  This will allow you to start and stop services.

The command line command to start the service is:

```
NET START MSSQL$*ServiceName*
```